# Поиск и удаление строки с unicodeescape в mssql на python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server

В SQL таблице есть столбец `sc_path`, в котором содержится запись `C:\Users\elebedev\Desktop\Python` Мне нужно удалить все строки в таблице содержащие эту запись.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 


path=r'C:\Users\elebedev\Desktop\Python'

con_log = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://log:pass@s1c/base')
sql_log = "DELETE FROM python_log WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, sc_path) = '{}' ".format(path)
with con_log.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sql_log)
```

Код выполняется, но он не видит эти строки. Как мне кажется, что это из за `unicodeescape` символа, но это не точно.

Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: вас интересуют записи `содержащие эту запись` или идентичные этой записи?

Comment: +1 что-то было такое, выборка через cx_Oracle, не возвращала(игнорировала) строки таблицы, содержащие unicodeescape, хотя тот же самый select в toad их показывал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете `raw string` - соответственно Python сам "заэкранирует" обратные слеши:

```
In [57]: path=r'C:\Users\elebedev\Desktop\Python'

In [58]: path
Out[58]: 'C:\\Users\\elebedev\\Desktop\\Python'
```

Если вас интересуют строки, начинающиеся с данной подстроки, то запрос нужно изменить:

```
sql_log = "DELETE FROM python_log WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, sc_path) like CONVERT(NVARCHAR, %s)"
parms = (f"{path}%", )
# NOTE:          ^ ^
con_log.execute(sql_log, parms)
```

Comment: Помоему, тут `"%{}%"` первый '%' можно убратъ. Что там может стоятъ слева?

Comment: @0xdb, согласен, если в этом поле может храниться только путь...

Comment: Ну да, имя поля `sc_path`, и  если туда кто-то что-то другое запишет, то я буду плакать.

Comment: @MaxU выдает ошибку Incorrect syntax near '?'. Если в sql запросе знак вопроса беру в апострофы, то код выполняется, но данные он все равно не видит :(

Comment: @LesNick, как вы создаете объект `conn`? Вы используете `sqlalchemy` или напрямую `pymssql` без посредников?

Comment: @MaxU                                                                                                                                     from sqlalchemy import create_engine  

con_log = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://log:pass@s1c/base')

Comment: @LesNick, а вы случайно не забыли указать параметры: `conn.execute(sql_log, parms)` ?

Comment: @MaxU нет, не забыл

Comment: @LesNick, очень странно. SQL Alchemy должен поддерживать все [paramstyle's](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle). Попробуйте заменить в ответе знак вопроса на `%s` - только не надо ничего обрамлять кавычками / апострофами

Comment: @MaxU код отрабатывает, но удалять, не удаляет. Добавил строку в SQL со значением sc_path=elebedev. Она удаляется без проблем.

Comment: @LesNick, можно попробовать так: `WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, sc_path) like CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ?)`

Comment: @MaxU на знак вопроса он у меня все время ошибку выдает: Incorrect syntax near '?'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n"). Я заменил на %s и он удалил :))

Answer (score 0):

Удалить как хотелось не получилось. Сделал чуток по другому. Но изначальным вариантом было бы интересней.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
path='elebedev'
con_log = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://login:passw@server/base')
sql_log = "DELETE FROM python_log WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, sc_path) like %s"
parms = (f"%{path}%", )
# NOTE:    ^     ^ ^
con_log.execute(sql_log, parms)
```